# Checking for completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ with metric defined by $d_1(x,y) =\mid e^x - e^y \mid$

Tags: metric-spaces

I have to check for completeness of following metric spaces

$1)$ :  $\mathbb{R}$ with metric defined by $d_1(x,y) =\mid e^x - e^y \mid$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

$2)$:   $\mathbb{Q}$ with metric defined by $d_2(x,y) = 1$, for all $x, y\in \mathbb{Q}, ~~ x \neq y$.

I have shown that $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$ is complete metric space. For that I took Cauchy sequence $(x_n)\subset\mathbb{R}$ that must  converge to some point say $x$ with respect to standard metric say $d$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete then).

The exponential
function is continuous so the sequence $e^{(x_n)}$ converges to $e^{x}$ with respect to standard metric of $\mathbb{R}$

from here we can conclude that $(x_n)$ converges to x w.r.t. $d_1$.

Hence $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$ is complete.

For second I am not able to figure out how to proceed. But intuitively I think it is complete.  Because given metric looks like discreet metric.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any alternate way to solve this problem?

Thanks for giving me time.

Comment: For $d_{1}$, note that you must start with an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R},d_{1})$ and not in the standard metric. The current argumentation does not show that $d_{1}$ is complete.

Comment: For the first problem: consider $x_n=-n$. For the second problem: you can quite explicitly describe Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @Norbert For second part Cauchy sequences are eventually constant sequences . Am i correct?

Comment: @srijan, yes.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Norbert Thank you very much.

Comment: For the first part note that it is isometric to $\mathbb{R}_+$ with the standard metric under the exponential map $\mathop{exp}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and its inverse $\ln:\mathbb{R}_+ \to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ThomasE. Thanks for your comment.$X_n = -n$ is cauchy sequence with respect to metric $d_1$ but it is not convergent and hence not complete. right?

Comment: @srijan: yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ThomasE. Thanks again.

Comment: @WillieWong That mean all the metric $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ will share same metric properties. Am i right? I am sorry I didn't get your comment? Could you please explain little more?

Comment: A Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}_+$ (with the standard metric) which _doesn't converge_ will, under the maps indicated, become a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ which doesn't converge. It may be easier to visualize what are the required Cauchy sequences on $\mathbb{R}_+$ with the standard metric.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your comment.  Now I got your point. Definiely exp map will determine isometry between $(\mathbb{R}, d_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{+}, d)$. Then we can take cauchy sequence say $(1/n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which doesn't converges. And by isometry we may conclude that what you have said above. Am i right?

Comment: @srijan: yes. Note that Thomas E's example corresponds to the Cauchy sequence $e^{-n}$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$. With the above you see that you get a wealth of examples. Now that you understood everything, I suggest you write up a consolidated answer and post it below (once the software allows you to). You can even earn the "self-learner" badge!

Comment: @WillieWong  Got much more than I was expected. Thank you very much.:)

Comment: Could you please explain me why $x_n=-n$ does not converge in $d_1$ metric? Does not it converges to $0$ in that metric?

Comment: @Mex if it converges to zero then $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d_1 (-n, 0)\rightarrow 0$. Is this happening here?

Comment: O ha thik kotha srijan bujhlam, $d_1(-n,0)\rightarrow 1$ right?