# A not complete metric space?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Please ,how to prove that the space $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the metric $d(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$ is  not a complete space?

I don't find a Cauchy sequence   but not convergent

Please

Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Can you think of a sequence $(x_n)$ where the Cauchy difference $d(x_n, x_m)$ gets small even though the $x_n$ themselves do not?

Comment: Is your statement even true?

Comment: @TheOscillator i don't understand

Comment: We know that $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y) =|x-y|$ is a complete metric space. Since the exponential function is continuous, then we usually would expect the $|e^{x}-e^{y}|$ should be small aswell... But maybe it has something to so with uniformness..

Comment: @TheOscillator: No, continuity of the exponential doesn't suggest that the new metric is complete, and in fact it isn't.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153707/checking-for-completeness-of-mathbbr-with-metric-defined-by-d-1x-y-mi

Comment: @TheOscillator: If $e^x$ were a slowly-growing function (e.g. with $e^x<x$) we might expect that $|x-y|$ small implies $|e^x-e^y|$ small. But we know that actually it is a very quickly-growing function; it's not obvious that this means $|e^x-e^y|$ is not small, but it lends some plausibility to the claim. (I don't know if you were intending your comments as a pedagogical device, but either way this may be useful to the OP as well.)

Comment: As Martin suggests, this is a duplicate of [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153707/checking-for-completeness-of-mathbbr-with-metric-defined-by-d-1x-y-mi) which is answered in the comments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Consider the sequence $x_n=-n$.  Clearly it doesn't converge. For, suppose $x_n \to x$ for some real number $x$. Then $|e^{-n}−e^x|→0$. Hence, $e^x=0$, which cannot be.

However, $N<n<m \implies |e^{x_n}-e^{x_m}|=e^{-n}-e^{-m}<e^{-N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.  So the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: how you see that it soesn't converge with this metric ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou whether or not a sequence converges doesn't depend on the metric. Whether or not it is a Cauchy sequence does.

Comment: you just do $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} -n=-\infty $ that's all ?

Comment: Suppose $x_n \to x$ for some real number $x$.  Then $|e^{-n}-e^x| \to 0$.  Hence, $e^x=0$, which cannot be.  So the sequence doesn't converge with the given metric.

Comment: @MattSamuel Uh? Whether a sequence converges or not is highly dependent on the metric. [See this for example.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055648/is-there-a-metric-in-which-1234-cdot-converges-to-frac112)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if two metrics induce the same topology, then they have the same convergent sequences. Convergence depends only on the topology.

Comment: i have a defiition we say that sequence is convergent if : $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq n_0, d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, but the topology depends on the metric... You would need to prove that this new metric induces the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi looking at your example, notice that the accepted answer says that the metric given there does not induce the usual topology on the real numbers.

Comment: The sequence is Cauchy. It does not converge to any real number, because such a real number would need to satisfy $e^x=0$.

Comment: juste why $e^{-n}-e^{-m}<e^{-N}$ please

Comment: Note that $e^{-x}$ is a positive, decreasing function.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a less direct way of viewing the problem. The function $f(x) = e^x$ defines an isometry from your metric space to the set $\mathbb{R}^+$ of positive real numbers with the usual metric. This fact is straightforward: $f$ is a bijection (the inverse function is the natural logarithm), and if $d$ is your metric and $d_1$ is the usual metric, then for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$d(x,y) = |e^x - e^y| = |(f(x) - f(y)| = d_1(f(x),f(y)).$$

So, $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^+, d_1)$ are isomorphic as metric spaces. We can see that the latter space is not complete by considering any sequence in $\mathbb{R}^+$ converging to 0. Such a sequence is Cauchy, but does not converge to a point of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Nice answer!  I think it makes it even more clear why we should consider a Cauchy sequence tending to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: Is $d(-100,-101)$ a large, medium, or small number? Look at the graph of $y=e^x$.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: That's right. And what about $d(-100,n)$ for integers $n<-101$?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Now try to use that observation to find a really simple sequence of negative integers that diverges even though it's $d$-Cauchy.